# How will i add search bar in google map for ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, uisearchbar

Here's my code in adding map and `UISearchBar`, but my search bar cannot be seen in view.

```
-(void)setCamera {
    camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLatitude
                                     longitude:currentLongitude
                                          zoom:8];

    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, searchBar.frame.size.height);
    [mapView_ addSubview:searchBar];
    self.view = mapView_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//create a search bar with 0 width and 0 height
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

//set the frame to 0 height because line above sets the height to zero.
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, searchBar.frame.size.height);


//maybe something like this?
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 44);
```

Comment: Try adding a simple UIView with red color as the background to see if any view you add actually shows up?

Answer (score 0):

[mapView_ bringsubViewToFront]
Try this